# How do I get Stack Overflow answers inside a terminal?

Tags: terminal, automation

Is there a way to query Stack Overflow directly from the command line and get back the most upvoted answer to the first question that comes up for that query?

I really mislike having to open up my browser whenever I want to brush up on my knowledge of writing RegExes for matching XHTML tags.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is possible! Try out Benjamin Gleitzman's excellent tool [howdoi](https://github.com/gleitz/howdoi).

It works like this:

```
$ howdoi get stackoverflow answers inside a terminal
```

and the program will query StackOverflow for keywords "get stackoverflow answers inside a terminal", find the question that best matches these terms and return the code from the best answer to that question.

You can also add the `-a` option to get the full answer, not just the code. So to get an answer for your example query, you would do:

```
$ howdoi -a RegEx match XHTML tags
```

### Installation

If you have Python & pip installed, you can get it from the Cheese shop.

```
$ pip install howdoi
```

### More help

Enter `howdoi -h` for complete usage instructions.

Comment: on Mac => download from upper link: $ sudo python setup.py install

Comment: you can use pip on Mac, too.

Comment: Sir. I applaud you.